# Python Django with showing multiple details result in one user id per upload

Tags: django, python-3.x

First of all, i am new to python with only 2 months. I am facing a problem with my project code which is upload multiple file and show the result. My project was a resume parser, in my original source code it's allowed upload one resume per upload and also successful extract the data information from resume and filled in my template result.

When i try to upload more than one file per upload with my original source code, it show this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Mv8.png) .After that i changed my user details from get to filter. Although the error are fixed and also it successfully upload multiple file with once but my extracted result are blank and show none after i change get() to filter()
Besides that, i did tried to change my user detail model from foreign key to one to one field but it didn't solve the problem

This is my view with changed the `user_detail = UserDetails.objects.filter(user=user)` from get to filter on line 86

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)
        UserDetails.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
        Competencies.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
        MeasurableResults.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
        Resume.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
        ResumeDetails.objects.filter(resume__user=user).delete()
        file_form = UploadResumeModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('resume')
        if file_form.is_valid():
            for file in files:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(id=1)

                    # saving the file
                    resume = Resume(user=user, resume=file)
                    resume.save()

                    # extracting resume entities
                    parser = resume_parser.ResumeParser(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, resume.resume.name))
                    data = parser.get_extracted_data()

                    # User Details
                    # resume.name          = data.get('name')
                    # resume.email         = data.get('email')
                    # resume.education     = get_education(data.get('education'))
                    user_details = UserDetails()
                    user_details.user           = user
                    user_details.name           = data.get('name')
                    user_details.email          = data.get('email')
                    user_details.mobile_number  = data.get('mobile_number')
                    user_details.skills         = ', '.join(data.get('skills'))
                    user_details.years_of_exp   = data.get('total_experience')
                    user_details.save()

                    for comp in data.get('competencies'):
                        competencies = Competencies()
                        competencies.user       = user
                        competencies.competency = comp
                        competencies.save()

                    for mr in data.get('measurable_results'):
                        measurable_results                   = MeasurableResults()
                        measurable_results.user              = user
                        measurable_results.measurable_result = mr
                        measurable_results.save()

                    # Resume Details
                    resume_details          = ResumeDetails()
                    resume_details.resume   = resume
                    resume_details.page_nos = data.get('no_of_pages')
                    resume_details.save()

                    # resume.experience    = ', '.join(data.get('experience'))
                    # measurable_results.append(data.get('measurable_results'))
                    # resume.save()
                except IntegrityError:
                    messages.warning(request, 'Duplicate resume found:', file.name)
                    return redirect('homepage')

            resumes = Resume.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(id=1))
            user_detail = UserDetails.objects.filter(user=user)
            messages.success(request, 'Resumes uploaded!')

            overall_score = 0

            competencies = data.get('competencies')
            measurable_results = data.get('measurable_results')

            if competencies and measurable_results:
                overall_score = competencies.get('score') + measurable_results.get('score')

            if competencies:
                context = {
                    'resumes': resumes,
                    'competencies': competencies,
                    'measurable_results': measurable_results,
                    'no_of_pages': data.get('no_of_pages'),
                    'total_experience': data.get('total_experience'),
                    'user_details': user_detail,
                    'overall_score': overall_score
                    }
            else:
                context = {
                    'resumes': resumes,
                    'competencies': [],
                    'measurable_results': [],
                    'no_of_pages': data.get('no_of_pages'),
                    'total_experience': data.get('total_experience'),
                    'user_details': user_detail,
                    'overall_score': overall_score
                    }
            return render(request, 'base.html', context)
    else:
        form = UploadResumeModelForm()
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my model

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email           = models.EmailField('Email', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_number   = models.IntegerField('Mobile Number', null=True, blank=True)
    skills          = models.CharField('Skills', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    years_of_exp    = models.FloatField('Experience', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class Competencies(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competency      = models.CharField('Competency', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class MeasurableResults(models.Model):
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    measurable_result = models.CharField('Competency', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class Resume(models.Model):
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resume            = models.FileField('Upload Resumes', upload_to='resumes/')
    last_uploaded_on  = models.DateTimeField('Uploaded On', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

class ResumeDetails(models.Model):
    resume      = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page_nos    = models.IntegerField('Number of Pages', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resume.user.email

class UploadResumeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Resume
        fields = ['resume']
        widgets = {
            'resume': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }

# delete the resume files associated with each object or record
```

My base.html

```
<body style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    <div class="container-fluid">
      {% include 'messages.html' %}

      {% if form %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'homepage' %}" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 3%">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button type="submit" id="import" name="import" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 2%; border-radius: 0">Upload</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% elif resumes %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">
              <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 0;">Upload More</button>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Resume File</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Competencies</th>
                <th>Measurable Results</th>
                <th>Presentation</th>
                <th>Education</th>
                <th>Skills</th>
                <th>Experience</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for resume in resumes %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{{resume.resume.url}}" target="_blank">{{resume.resume.url|truncatechars:20}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{user_details.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{user_details.email}}</td>
                  <td>{{user_details.mobile_number}}</td>
                  <td>
                    {% with t=competencies %}
                    <b>Teamwork </b>({{t.teamwork|length}}): {{t.teamwork}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=competencies %}
                    <b>Analytical </b>({{t.analytical|length}}): {{t.analytical}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=competencies %}
                    <b>Result Driven </b>({{t.result_driven|length}}): {{t.result_driven}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=competencies %}
                    <b>Leadership </b>({{t.leadership|length}}): {{t.leadership}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=competencies %}
                    <b>Communication </b>({{t.communication|length}}): {{t.communication}}
                    {% endwith %}
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    {% with t=measurable_results %}
                    <b>Metrics </b>({{t.metrics|length}}): {{t.metrics}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=measurable_results %}
                    <b>Action Words </b>({{t.action_words|length}}): {{t.action_words}}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <br><br>
                    {% with t=measurable_results %}
                    <b>Weak Words </b>({{t.weak_words|length}}): {{t.weak_words}}
                    {% endwith %}
                  </td>
                  <td><b>No. of pages:</b> {{ no_of_pages }}, <b>Total Experience:</b> {{ total_experience }} years, <b>Overall Score:</b> {{ overall_score }}</td>
                  <td>{{resume.education}}</td>
                  <td>{{user_details.skills}}</td>
                  <td>{{resume.experience}}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

  </body>
```

What i am expect of the output is it able upload multiple file resume and also able to extract text information from each of the resume file successfully.
This is what i happened [NotExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5E0b.png) and what i expected is this result [ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYMcp.png).

Hope someone able help me to solve my problem or any suggestion to modify my code, it really does matter to me significantly and also my academic. Thank you !!!

Comment: it's not clear where you are looking at the results. Is this another view? After you posted the files, what do you see in django admin? Look at the various models and what was saved in the db. The biggest problem I see with your code is that you're using `data` which is extract from the uploaded file outside of the for-loop, ie its value is just the one from the last file from the for-loop.

Comment: you're also not showing your template **base.html** which displays the results.

Comment: @dirkgroten This is my main view, in my admin i can see the Competencies, Measurable results, Resume details, Resumes, User details. I uploaded my base.html

Comment: `user_details` is a queryset so it doesn’t have a attribute `name`.  And for all the other columns as I said `data` is just the last resume since it’s used outside the forloop. Your logic for creating the context is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you’re not saving the relationship between a resume and the other models so you can’t display which UserDetail or Competency belongs to each resume.

Comment: So how could i change my context and also the logic? This coding took me 2 months to do it. I have no idea and change it within 2 day before my submission. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Why are multiple resumes uploaded by the same user? I really don't understand the  business logic of the application you're building, why a user can have many different names for example? So no, I can't help. My guess it that your models are wrong in the first place, but I can't tell without knowing what the purpose of this application is.